# "customer_eav_attribute " Table what is "input_filter" and what values can you have in there

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-attribute, date, eav-attributes

I See in the customer_eav_attribute table there is a column "input_field", what is that? I see most values are "null2, but i do see "date" and "datetime", what other values can you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**customer_eav_attribute.input_filter** is used when a form is sent and the data is being extracted from the fields.
**customer_eav_attribute.input_filter** is field filter like date / datetime